# why are the StreamReader functions, ReadLineAsync and ReadToEndAsync so slow on a file?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, file, async-await

Does anyone know why `ReadLineAsync` and `ReadToEndAsync` are so much slower, than their synchronous counterparts `ReadLine` and `ReadToEnd`? I could understand the slowness if i was awaiting multiple calls, but that not the case.

I'm using a Release build, and i'm not starting it with debugging.

I tested it on a 420MB CSV file, containing only the following line repeated:

```
1234567890123456,12345678,12345678901,1,1,1,1234567890123456789
1234567890123456,12345678,12345678901,1,1,1,1234567890123456789
1234567890123456,12345678,12345678901,1,1,1,1234567890123456789
[etc...]
```

I tested it with the following program (results are in comments):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Restart();
    One_ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine($"One_ReadToEnd: {sw.Elapsed}"); // One_ReadToEnd: 00:00:06.1749275

    sw.Restart();
    One_ReadToEndAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine($"One_ReadToEndAsync: {sw.Elapsed}"); // One_ReadToEndAsync: 00:00:23.3265661

    sw.Restart();
    Many_ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Many_ReadLine: {sw.Elapsed}");  // Many_ReadLine: 00:00:05.9391718

    sw.Restart();
    Many_ReadLineAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine($"Many_ReadLineAsync: {sw.Elapsed}"); // Many_ReadLineAsync: 00:00:31.4988402
}

const string path = @"C:\Temp\test.csv";

static void One_ReadToEnd()
{

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }
}

static async Task One_ReadToEndAsync()
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        sr.Close();
    }
}

static void Many_ReadLine()
{

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            sr.ReadLine();

        sr.Close();
    }
}

static async Task Many_ReadLineAsync()
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            await sr.ReadLineAsync();

        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

These were the results:

```
One_ReadToEnd:      00:00:06.1749275
One_ReadToEndAsync: 00:00:23.3265661
Many_ReadLine:      00:00:05.9391718
Many_ReadLineAsync: 00:00:31.4988402
```

Comment: `One_ReadToEndAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is essentially equivalent to a blocking call, except with added overhead and nothing to do on the thread while the method awaits.

Comment: I would expect that Async would be slower than Sync because it has to handle the state engine. But the reason we use Async is to release the resources whilst we are waiting for a slow process (such as reading a file) to complete.

Comment: In other words, to get any benefit from the `async` machinery, there has to be something for the thread to do while your call is awaiting.  Making things `async` doesn't just magically speed things up; rather, it frees up your calling thread to do *other* useful work while the awaiting is occurring.

Comment: 99% of the time that is nothing except wait for the async call to finish - async was a bad copy of node.js concept and should have been much more used explicitly to make a call run asynchronously within synchronous methods.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - Can you please explain your comment in more detail?

Comment: If you are going to use the async flag and methods on a file stream, it's probably worth while increasing the buffer size (dramatically) to reduce some of the overhead. Also (although it likely doesn't matter in this scenario) the Stopwatch class is not a good benchmarking tool

Comment: @RobertHarvey i get that it frees up the calling thread. i'm also expecting the async versions to be a little bit slower, but not by this much

Comment: @TheGeneral what do you recommend instead of Stopwatch?

Comment: @gbjbaanb That is not strictly true. Most modern kernels force IO to be async under the hood anyway, so the overhead is not as much as it might seem. All that sync IO does is block on a wait-handle for the async IO to finish, so a context switch etc is necessary anyway

Comment: @Enigmativity I mean nearly all the "async" code I see is "await XXX", ie it might yield to events, but all it does here is wait for completion before continuing - ie effectively synchronous. I never see CPU bound work running async because nobody does Task.Run() in async methods, and they generally await it immediately too. It seems to me that all the async code made matters a lot more complicated for no benefit except to event-driven UI, and that could have been solved much easier using a thread.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - I feel you're confusing asynchrony with concurrency.

Comment: @Enigmativity not really. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async?redirectedfrom=MSDN) show async is both, depending on whether you're doing IO or CPU work,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, its not apples-to-apples

sync:
`using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.ASCII))`

and async:
`using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous), Encoding.ASCII))`

see the difference (no, not the 4096 - that's the default buffer size), but the FileOptions.Asynchronous. This does not make the streamreader asynchronous, but makes opening the file in async mode - ie the file can be read or written asychronously ("overlapped" in windows-speak)

Normally this shouldn't make a difference, but who knows what layers of code is in there, so try without the filestream options and see if that changes things.

the docs say:

```
    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("existingfile.txt"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Opened file.");
        result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + result);
    }
```

in the ReadToEndAsync documentation, so its not necessary to open the file overlapped to get your app running asynchronously. Or you can try opening the file in overlapped mode in your synchronous version.

---

Edit: Had a quick look at [the source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs), it all seems the same logic between sync and async CS code even if it accesses the streams via properties and is littered with GetAwait type calls, but the async section has this comment. I can't find the referenced bug but maybe this is causing the massive slowdown in accessing the file.

> ```
>     // Access to instance fields of MarshalByRefObject-derived types requires special JIT helpers that check
>     // if the instance operated on is remote. This is optimised for fields on this but if a method is Async
>     // and is thus lifted to a state machine type, access will be slow.
>     // As a workaround, we either cache instance fields in locals or use properties to access such fields.
>
>     // See Dev11 bug #370300 for more info.
> ```

Comment: oh. your example does seem to run faster at 00:00:14.8096422, so this is very helpful

Comment: using the same StreamReader for the sync that i was using for async indeed slows things down a lot. it's about as bad!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be [StreamReader.ReadLineAsync performance can be improved](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62061).

In the issue's thread there are benchmarks done with BenchmarkDotNet with a comment from a Microsoft dev below the results:

> My observations:
>
> - .NET 6 is 12-13% faster on average. If IO was the limiting factor, I would expect the difference to be larger for async method.
> - Sync implementation is as twice as fast as async. This is expected, as async File IO has some non trivial overhead compared to sync. The main benefit of async File IO is improved scalability, not performance.
>
> I had a quick look at the implementation and there is definitely place for improvement. I am going to change the issue title (there is no such thing as Stream.ReadLineAsync) and it's 2 (not 6) times slower and make it up-for-grabs.

The work to improve this was included in [System.IO work planned for .NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64596) but as of Jan 2023 with .NET7.0.100 released the issue is still open and the async versions seem to be 2x slower than the non-async ones.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. i hope it gets fixed at some point. i also need to take a look at BenchmarkDotNet. thanks for mentioning this tool

Comment: [#69888 Fix StreamReader EOF handling and improve perf](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/69888)  was merged for .NET 8.